# How to remove the extra space from all text boxes in php code

Tags: removing-whitespace

I want to add a function to remove all extra spaces from the text written in the text boxes in my php code. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about word separator spaces and want really serial string:

```
$string = 'forexample string with space   and more';
$no_space = str_replace(" ","",$string);
```